# How to apply texture on material with cartoon style?

Tags: texturing, materials, image, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

[image]

Hello! So for the character i'm making, it has a toon style (i use 'constant' for the interpolation for the color ramp, node is on the image.) I want to add line details on the body using textures while still having that toon shading for the body. I don't know how to. Can somebody explain to me how to do it?
(note I'm quite new to Blender, so please explain in a way I can understand if you can :))

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine Toon Shading effects with existing textures, use a MixRGB Node to Multiply the Image texture by the shadow values from the Toon Shader setup. I often multiply it twice to really drive home the shadow effect. In the first example below, I used a full PBR texture on the object, just to show that mixing like this works with PBR as well, but of course it works just fine with a single Image Texture (second image).

[image: ToonPBR]

[image: ToonImage]

If you're adding "colored shadows" from a ColorRamp, it will work just fine, however I would still recommend multiplying it by the "shadow values" of a black and white ColorRamp as well, to really intensify the shadow effect. You can always turn down the mix factor if it is too strong. (For the record, in this image, I used the roughness map of this texture as a BaseColor, just so I had a black and white texture (simulating your "texture lines") that I could mix with the colored ColorRamp to get the end result - I'm assuming this will be closer to your actual setup)

[image: ToonColors]

Answer (score 0):

In cycles you can detect edges better, but there is no shader to rgb node.

In eevee which you are on do this:
[image]

It may not be exactly what you what but it is a simple way for detecting edges in eevee node editor.

The other thing you might want to look into is freestyle.

You can also create a black and white texture in texture paint and overlay that using a mix node set to multiply.